# What does the name of "Julia" (the programming language) refer to?

Tags: julia

Is the name "Julia" anything to do with [Julia sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set) in mathematics?

Comment: That's not a question very fit for Stack Overflow, but see this [discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5499).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about programming.

Comment: Should be moved to http://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jubobs IMO this is a valid on-topic question, even though it's not technical - it's not opinion-based or unclear, there is an answer and it's about Julia. There are many similar questions here about other languages. I think the internet benefits from having a canonical answer here (also I think it's most-likely off-topic on hsm).

Comment: @AndyHayden Ok. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 18):

No. See [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/6xEWQz_mK10) on the mailing list:

> *[Steven G. Johnson](http://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/)*
>   [Alan Edelman](http://www-math.mit.edu/~edelman/) told me specifically that it was not named after the fractal, and in fact that "Julia" doesn't refer to anything in particular.   Apparently, it just came up in a random conversation years ago when someone suggested arbitrarily that "Julia" would be a good name for a programming language.

and on [quora](http://www.quora.com/Why-is-Julia-named-Julia):

> Jeff Bezanson's friend suggested it, and they just went along with the name.

*This quora post also mentions that this is again stated by Jeff and Stefan on video, which I think is [this one](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Stefan-Karpinski-and-Jeff-Bezanson-Julia-Programming-Language) (though there is no transcript, I also recall the same thing).*

Comment: This is indeed correct. In fact, Jeff had a friend who had suggested the name for an earlier project of Jeff's, which was called Julia. We adopted that name in the very early days. The Julia ASCII logo you see on startup is what Jeff had designed for this earlier project as well, and was adopted at the same time. You can see it in one of the really early commits.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/f1662b024063d80889a29f757deec82868f8da76 (it's fun looking back at early commits!) :)

Comment: @ViralBShah I wonder if that was the reason for the 2 (which makes it read like Julia^2).